# How to set instance variables in a class that includes a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to create a DSL for any classes that include my module. It is dealing with stocks.

Here's my test:

```
    context 'when price is provided' do 
        let(:stock_with_price) {
            class Stock
                include StopLimit
                stock_attributes price: 3.33
            end

            Stock.new
        }
        it 'sets the price to given value' do 
            stock_with_price.price.should eq(3.33)
        end
    end
```

This is my module so far:

```
    module StopLimit
      DEFAULT_STOCK_PRICE = 0
      def self.included(base)
        attr_accessor :price
        def base.stock_attributes(options = {})
            define_method('price') do 
                instance_variable_get("@price") ? instance_variable_get("@price") : DEFAULT_STOCK_PRICE
            end
            options.each_pair do |attribute, value|
                if self.method_defined?(attribute)
                        instance_variable_set("@#{attribute.to_s}", value)
                        # raise instance_variable_get("@price").inspect <-- This prints out 3.33!
                    end
            end
        end
      end
    end
```

My tests seem to be broken. `stock.price` is returning `0`. Why does the instance variable print the right thing, but my test fail?

UPDATE:

This works:

```
    options.each_pair do |attribute, value|
        if self.method_defined?(attribute)
            @price = value
            end
    end
```

However, it's hardcoded. How would I dynamically create and set the instance variable value, so that I could loop through all attribute and value pairs and create @[[attribute]] = value for each?

Answer (score 0):

Because `instance_variable_set` is being called in a class method, `self` is set to the class and `@price` is getting set as a class instance variable on `Stock`.

However, your `price` method is an *instance* method, so it tries to find `@price` on the instance, doesn't find it, and returns the default.

EDIT:
How about this:

```
define_method('price') do 
  @price ||= self.class.instance_variable_get(:@price) || DEFAULT_STOCK_PRICE
end
```

Comment: So how do I actually set the default instance variable of the class instance?

Comment: @Edmund why do you want it to be an instance variable if it's a property of the class? Or, conversely, why do you call `stock_attributes` in the class definition if it defines an instance attribute?

Comment: @Edmund I maybe I understand. I have updated my answer with a working solution.